# AngularJS conditional ng-disabled does not re-enable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Given a conditionally disabled text input field using `ng-disabled="truthy_scope_variable"`, AngularJS disables the field the *first time* the scope variable is falsified, but does not enable it on subsequent changes. As a result, the field remains disabled. I can only assume something went wrong, but the Console log is empty.

The truthy scope variable is tied to a radio button model and I can even `$watch` it change, but the input field's `ng-disabled` is not working as expected. I have manually tried calling `$apply`, but it looks like Angular is triggering DOM changes.

### In controller:

```
$scope.new_account = true
```

### Radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="new_account" name="register"
 id="radio_new_account" value="true" />

<input type="radio" ng-model="new_account" name="register"
 id="radio_existing_account" value="false" />
```

### Conditionally disabled input field:

```
<input type="password" ng-disabled="new_account" id="login-password"
 name="password" ng-model="password" />
```

If I initially set `$scope.new_account = false`, the field is rendered disabled, but never re-enabled. Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you tried using just checkbox instead of radio button. It's neater. Look at this http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngDisabled

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is an alternative solution available just use

> ng-value

```
 <input type="radio" ng-model="new_account" name="register"
 id="radio_new_account" ng-value="true" />

<input type="radio" ng-model="new_account" name="register"
 id="radio_existing_account" ng-value="false" />
      <input type="password" ng-disabled="new_account" id="login-password"
 name="password" ng-model="password" />
```

Comment: Your ng-value advice also fixes the problem! I wish I could mark both your answers as correct.

Comment: After working with AngularJS some more, `ng-value` seems the more idiomatic way. If you update your answer with why it works, I'll mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 32):

That's because HTML attributes are always strings, so in your example ngDisabled is evaluating a string in both cases ("true" or "false").

To remedy, you should compare the model against the string value in ngDisabled:

```html
ng-disabled="new_account == 'false'"
```

... or use a checkbox, to get the actual boolean value:

```html
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="existing_account" name="register" id="checkbox_new_account" />
<label for="checkbox_new_account">Is Existing Account</label>

Password:
<input type="password" ng-disabled="existing_account" name="password" ng-model="password" />
```

Here's a [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/KmQXXEJBEVjsAvsFDl0C?p=preview) with both solutions.

Comment: using ng-value is simpler way to do with radio button

Answer (score 1):

As of 2016 March the binded values will update the ui in Chrome and Firefox even when the ng-disabled is true but not in Safari. In Safari when you use ng-disabled the ui wont update although the input element `value` property will have the updated value (Check `element.value` after changing it.)

In Safari to force the ui updates with `ng-model` or `ng-value` directives you have to use ng-readonly instead of ng-disabled.