# AngularJS input text disabled by select option

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-disabled

I've a simple form with a `<select>` and an `<input text>`; what I need is to disable the input text if the value of an option is true. This is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="auth">{{ 'SETTINGS.SYSTEM.NET.WIFI.AUTH.LABEL' | translate }}</label>
    <select name="auth" class="form-control"  ng-model="wifi.securitytype">
        <option value="true">{{ 'SETTINGS.SYSTEM.NET.WIFI.AUTH.NONE' | translate }}</option>
        <option value="false">{{ 'SETTINGS.SYSTEM.NET.WIFI.AUTH.WEP' | translate }}</option>
        <option value="false">{{ 'SETTINGS.SYSTEM.NET.WIFI.AUTH.WPA2' | translate }}</option>
    </select>
</div>


<fieldset ng-disabled="wifi.securitytype">
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':wifiForm.password.$invalid && !wifi.securitytype}">
        <label for="password">{{ 'SETTINGS.SYSTEM.NET.WIFI.PASSWORD' | translate }}</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="{{ 'SETTINGS.SYSTEM.NET.WIFI.PASSWORD_PLACEHOLDER' | translate }}" ng-model="wifi.wpakey" ng-pattern='/^(?!\s*$).+/' ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }">
        <span class="help-block ng-hide" ng-show="wifiForm.password.$invalid && !wifi.securitytype">RICHIESTA PASSWORD DI RETE</span>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

The problem is that the `<fieldset>` is ever disabled. Where is my fault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you expect the option values to be of a boolean type. But HTML attributes are always strings, so you should evaluate them in both cases, "true" or "false", as pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855304/angularjs-conditional-ng-disabled-does-not-re-enable)

Try to replace the **ng-disabled** condition with

```
<fieldset ng-disabled="'true' === wifi.securitytype">
```

Answer (score 0):

`wifi.securitytype` will return `'true'` or `'false'` which are non empty strings and truthy according to javascript, so your `ng-disabled` always evaluates to `true`. you can do as suggested by @Eirini.